# Какой скрипт для замены значений в XML является более корректным

Tags: sql-server, xml, replace, xquery

Есть в таблице XML вида

```
 '<MyData>
<Text name="MyFirstName" secondname="MySecondName" />
</MyData>'
```

Нужно заменить имя MyFirstName на MyNewFirstName.
Есть два способа

1)

```
update @MyTable 
set MyXML = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(MAX), MyXML),'<Text name="MyFirstName"','<Text name="MyNewFirstName"' )
```

2. 

```
update @MyTable
set MyXML.modify('replace value of (/MyData/Text[@name = "MyFirstName"]/@name)[1] with ("MyNewFirstName")' )
```

2й выглядит более XQuery, но требует и больше ресурсов(выполняется дольше).
Какой бы выбрали вы?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку тип данных столбца - XML, его собственный метод XQuery безопаснее и лучше. XML чувствителен к регистру. Кроме того, значение атрибутов XML может быть заключено в одинарные кавычки. Таким образом, функция REPLACE () не сработает.

Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за: [SQL Server vNext (post 2019) and NoSQL functionality](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<MyData>
    <Text name="MyFirstName" secondname="MySecondName"/>
</MyData>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @var VARCHAR(30) = 'MyNewFirstName';

UPDATE @tbl
SET xmldata.modify('replace value of (/MyData/Text[@name = "MyFirstName"]/@name)[1]
    with (sql:variable("@var"))' );

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```